# Destructuring an object in JS

Tags: javascript

The solution I have written is working as expected, but here is my function:

```
const dataExtraction = () => {
  const { id, name, sprites, types } = data;
  const pokemonType= types[0].type.name;
  const { front_default } = sprites;
  const animated= sprites.versions['generation-v']['black-white'].animated.front_default;
  
  return { 
         id, //6
         name, //charizard
         pokemonType, //fire
         front_default, //image url
         aniamted //image url
  }
}
```

I have the JSON payload below and I have extracted data that I would like to use. I have followed a pretty standard way to navigate into the nested objects but I would like to get people opinion if there is a better solution or cleaner way of writing above function:

https://pastebin.com/7LUPLbMm

Comment: `aniamted` -> `animated` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using an arrow function as inline function does not make the code very readable.
2. Why assign variables if they are only used once?

```js
function extractData (json) {  
    return { 
        id: json.id,
        name: json.name,
        pokemonType: json.types[0].type.name,
        front_default: json.sprites.front_default,
        animated: json.sprites.versions['generation-v']['black-white'].animated.front_default
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A super short review;

- `data` seems to be a global variable with a super generic name, that's a bad idea
- Destructuring is cool, but personally, this feels like too much
- function names are often `<verb><subject>` so perhaps `extractData`, or even `extractPokemon`?
- I like your use of `const` and comments

I was going to write a counter example, but Richard N took care of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [two](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276349#276353) [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276349#276354) answers offer improvements, but I'd like to throw another suggestion into the mix :)

When dealing with JSON like this, the fragility from the deep lookups send shivers down my spine - it looks error prone to me, because if the data or data shape changes, e.g. has `undefined` or `null` somewhere in the chain, this code is going to break.

Rather than suggest a try/catch approach, which could work, I'd recommend that you use a well tested library method such as [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) from lodash.

You'll then have something a bit more robust, like so:

```js
import { get } from 'lodash';

const mapJsonToPokemonItem = (data) => ({
  id: get(data, 'id'),
  name: get(data, 'name'),
  pokemonType: get(data, 'types[0].type.name'),
  front_default: get(data, 'sprites.front_default'),
  animated: get(data, "sprites.versions['generation-v']['black-white'].animated.front_default"),
});
```

Note the following:

1. I've named the function `mapJsonToPokemonItem` in an attempt to better describe what the function actually does.
2. Accept the `data` as an argument, to avoid reliance on the outside scope for this variable.
3. Directly return an object with the `=> ({})` syntax, as there's no real need for execution within the function, other than the mapping.
4. You can optionally provide a default value for the `get` calls, e.g.: `get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default')`, which may be useful for fallback images, etc.

Comment: "*if the data or data shape changes, this code is going to break*" - I would think that's expected. I would *want* my code to cause an exception if the data has a different shape than anticipated, instead of silently coercing it to `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi How you handle the changed/missing data shape is mostly subjective. I've put forward something graceful, if viewing partial data is acceptable, but I understand your POV. I guess we'd need input from the OP on what they'd prefer to do, and what makes sense for their users. Thanks for the edit btw :)

Comment: If you are using a modern runtime environment (or a JS compiler such as Babel) then instead of lodash's `get` you should also consider [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It has the advantage not to "hide" the properties in a string: `data?.sprites?.versions?.['generation-v']?.['black-white']?.animated?.front_default`

Comment: Since when are *magic strings* considered robust? If at all I try to avoid all *magic values* in my code because they most of the time typos in them can't be caught during compile time.